# How to load obj model in C# and OpenTK 4

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm trying to load an obj model in C# Opentk 4 but it is written in the console: "the format of the input string is incorrect" can someone help me please. I just want to load obj model this is my OpenGL dream but i can't.

Here is my one-file code:

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Input;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OpenGLTest {
    class Model {
        private List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        private List<Vector3> normals = new List<Vector3>();
        private List<Vector2> texCoords = new List<Vector2>();
        private List<int> indices = new List<int>();

        private int vaoID, vboID, eboID;
        private int vertexCount;

        public Model(string fileName) {
            LoadObj(fileName);
            InitBuffers();
        }

        private void LoadObj(string fileName) {
            StreamReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
                string line;
                while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    if(line.StartsWith("v ")) {
                        string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');
                        float x = float.Parse(tokens[1]);
                        float y = float.Parse(tokens[2]);
                        float z = float.Parse(tokens[3]);
                        vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y, z));
                    } else if(line.StartsWith("vn ")) {
                        string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');
                        float x = float.Parse(tokens[1]);
                        float y = float.Parse(tokens[2]);
                        float z = float.Parse(tokens[3]);
                        normals.Add(new Vector3(x, y, z));
                    } else if(line.StartsWith("vt ")) {
                        string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');
                        float u = float.Parse(tokens[1]);
                        float v = float.Parse(tokens[2]);
                        texCoords.Add(new Vector2(u, v));
                    } else if(line.StartsWith("f ")) {
                        string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');
                        for(int i = 1; i < tokens.Length; i++) {
                            string[] parts = tokens[i].Split('/');
                            int vi = int.Parse(parts[0]) - 1;
                            int ti = int.Parse(parts[1]) - 1;
                            int ni = int.Parse(parts[2]) - 1;
                            vertices.Add(vertices[vi]);
                            texCoords.Add(texCoords[ti]);
                            normals.Add(normals[ni]);
                            indices.Add(vertexCount++);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally {
                if(reader != null) reader.Close();
            }
        }

        private void InitBuffers() {
            float[] vertexData = new float[vertexCount * 8];
            for(int i = 0, vi = 0, ti = 0, ni = 0; i < vertexCount; i++, vi += 3, ti += 2, ni += 3) {
                vertexData[i * 8] = vertices[vi].X;
                vertexData[i * 8 + 1] = vertices[vi].Y;
                vertexData[i * 8 + 2] = vertices[vi].Z;
                vertexData[i * 8 + 3] = normals[ni].X;
                vertexData[i * 8 + 4] = normals[ni].Y;
                vertexData[i * 8 + 5] = normals[ni].Z;
                vertexData[i * 8 + 6] = texCoords[ti].X;
                vertexData[i * 8 + 7] = texCoords[ti].Y;
            }

            GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out vaoID);
            GL.BindVertexArray(vaoID);

            GL.GenBuffers(1, out vboID);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vboID);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexData.Length * sizeof(float), vertexData, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 8 * sizeof(float), 0);

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 8 * sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 8 * sizeof(float), 6 * sizeof(float));

            GL.GenBuffers(1, out eboID);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, eboID);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, indices.Count * sizeof(int), indices.ToArray(), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        }

        public void Draw() {
            GL.BindVertexArray(vaoID);
            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, indices.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
        }
    }

    class Game {
        private const int Width = 800;
        private const int Height = 600;

        private GameWindow window;
        private Model model;

        public Game() {
            window = new GameWindow(Width, Height, GraphicsMode.Default, "OpenGL Test");
            window.Load += OnLoad;
            window.RenderFrame += OnRenderFrame;
        }

        private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
            model = new Model("bunny.obj");
        }

        private void OnRenderFrame(object sender, FrameEventArgs e) {
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            model.Draw();

            window.SwapBuffers();
        }

        public void Run() {
            window.Run(60.0);
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Game game = new Game();
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Also sorry if i make mystake in my question because:
1-I'm newbie in programming
2-I'm newbie in stackoverflow (first question ever)
3-I'm french so sorry for my bad english

Comment: Check if your `float.Parse` accepts , or . as a decimal delimiter. Check file and test on a simple string. Use CultureInvariant anyway...